# union-of-connected-subsets-is-connected-if-intersection-is-nonempty

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

[Union of connected subsets is connected if intersection is nonempty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425007/union-of-connected-subsets-is-connected-if-intersection-is-nonempty)

I don't understand why A∩F and B∩F are relatively open where Brian Scott commented.

Thanks

Comment: $A, B$ are open in $\bigcup F$ and $F \subset \bigcup F$. Thus $A\cap F, B\cap F$ are relatively open in $F$.

Comment: Why not ask this on the other page? There is a tool named *comments*...

Comment: @Did I suppose that the reason might be that the OP is [below 50 reputation points](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), so they can only comment on their posts and answers to their questions. (This does not change the fact that this question is a bit unclear. It refers to a *comment* by Brian M. Scott. I guess the OP wanted to refer to *answer* by Brian M. Scott...?)

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about the 2 comments after Brian M. Scott's answer. It is not clear to the OP why $A\cap F$ and $B\cap F$ are relatively open in $F$.

Answer (score 2):

$A \cap F$ and $B \cap F$ are open in $F$ by definition of subspace topology on $F$. A subset $X$ of $F$ is open in $F$ iff there exists an open subset $U$ of $M$ such that $X = F \cap U$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $\bigcup \mathscr{F}$ there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $M$ such that $A=U \bigcap (\bigcup \mathscr{F})$ and $B = V \bigcap (\bigcup \mathscr{F})$. So $A\cap F = U \cap F$ and $B \cap F = V \cap F$, making them open in $F$.